# Windows 10 freezes from time to time

Tags: windows-10, ssd, freeze

I am not sure if this is a right place to ask, but lately, my notebook freezes very frequently(it froze like 6 times in a row already). After the boot it may freeze in a minute or two easily. There is no BSoD or something like that, it just... Dies with a picture on the screen.  I completely reinstalled the windows and installed all the latest updates.

The thing might be new SSD which replaced HDD that was almost broken. But before that happened it could freeze anyway but much rarer, like once per month. When the freeze happens I can't input anything with a touchpad or keyboard but the screen remain bright and the music(if it was running) still plays.

There is almost nothing installed on it right now, all the drivers are installed by Windows 10 itself. I am not sure what you need to offer any solutions so, please, ask and I'll provide you any needed information.

The computer is original Dell Vostro 5470 with (new) SSD Kingston HyperX Fury 240GB with original Windows 10 aboard.

Comment: Could be a waste of time, but you should try to install the Nvidia drivers for your graphics card [link](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/120907/en-us)

Comment: @link thx for the reply. I did this few hours ago. Maybe I should reinstall everything including Windows and install ALL the drivers manually... Because it doesn't freeze when I go through memtest for like an hour.

Comment: "Dies with a picture on the screen" ... which picture?

Comment: @spike_66 I am sorry. I meant everything freezes and the last frame of what happened on screen is there forever. Ans, actually, I found the source of the problem. The new NVidia drivers are broken so after I installed the one from Dell official website it stopped. But still. Some weird lags happen sometimes when notebook in sleep mode. Sometimes I can't "wake it up" so I need to reboot it with an emergency button. This notebook is sooo broken...

Comment: Then you should reinstall Windows and install the drivers that you find on Dell website.